# Some mobile phone gets the error “java.lang.NumberFormatException"

Tags: android

My app is all right on most of the phone.However,on some kinds of phone,it will get the error below:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '@2131492955' as integer
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1728)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1747)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:130)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(SourceFile:351)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3814)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:659)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '@2131492955' as integer
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:414)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:403)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:153)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:286)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2216)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:2358)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1503)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.installDecor(Unknown Source)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.initActionBar(Unknown Source)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat.getActionBar(Unknown Source)
    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.getSupportActionBar(Unknown Source)
    at com.qingdaonews.bus.BaseActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at com.qingdaonews.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1692)
    ... 11 more
```

And the version of Android is supported by my apps so I wonder why it gets this error.
And in fact there is not a variable like that.The rom is a custom build of a device producter but many customers use the rom.

Comment: May be it is because of the version of android on your phones.

Comment: @Midhun The version of the phone is 2.3,but most Android 2.3 could run it

Comment: We can't parse '@2131492955' as integer. Try to fix that and every thing will be fine. I will try to help if you post your code.

Comment: '@' is not an integer though

Comment: I know '@2131492955' is not an integer,but there is no '@2131492955' in my apps so the error is not existed in most phone.So I don't know why this kind of phone will cause this error

Comment: I'm not sure but @2131492955 sounds like a reference. Seems like that phone is doing something weird with the ActionBarSherlock resources? Hard to tell.

Comment: @dmon I think so.I aslo think it is doing something weird with the ActionBarSherlock but 2.3 really need ActionBarSherlock .So I do not know why the problem caused

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find where the `@` comes from, use this snippet to delete all non-digits from the `String`, and it will be parsed correctly:

```
String yourString;
int yourInt = Integer.parseInt(yourString.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
```

Comment: Thank you.But in fact I really don't know where the number comes.I think it's a problem caused by rom but I cannot find why

Comment: So the number might be wrong even after removing the '@'? Paste the code used to retrieve this number as a String.